# CSS issues with menu

Tags: html, css

I had a working menu on my site but when I moved it from one webhost to another it got a bit broken and I am not sure why as I haven't changed any files.

It looks like in the image below and naturally I want the blog item (and other items) to be aligned to the left and not have that grey box which is 2px something higher.
http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/2066/61967761.png

My CSS is:

```
#header {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:960px;
    height:174px;
    background:url(../App_Themes/logo01.png) no-repeat -2px 14px;
}

#header ul {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:right;
    height:38px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#header ul li {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    margin-left:2px;
}



#header li ul{
    background: rgb(211,211,211);
        display:none;
        height:auto;
        position:absolute;
        width:180px;
    z-index:200;
    margin-left: 9px;               
}

#header li li {
    display:block;
        float:left;
    padding: 0px;
    width:180px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    height: 25px;
}

#header li:hover ul{
        display:block;
}   

#header li ul li a {background-image: none; 
            color:#000;
            text-indent: 0px;
            font-family: Tahoma;
            font-size: 12px;
                    width: 180px;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-left: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#header li ul li a:hover {background-image: none;   
            background: rgb(26,66,126); 
            color:#fff;
}

#header .tagline {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:right;
    margin-top:40px;
    width:620px;
}
```

HTML example:

```
<div id="header">
<ul id="menuElem">
<li class="menublog">
<a href="... />
</li>
<li class="menuabout">
<a href="... />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: has your old server and new server same operation system ?

Comment: it's hard to tell if you do not have a working example to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Reset all margins and paddings for your ul and li and set margins again.

like:

```
#header ul {
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
float:right;
height:38px;
margin:0;
padding:0
}
```

same for li. It happens to me constantly while uploading new templates on production server.